# Find tags doesn’t contain specific attribute (specific word) using grep

Tags: visual-studio, regex, grep

How to find all server-side tags (`<asp:`) that doesn't contains attribute `runat` in my Visual Studio 2008 / MonoDevelop solution using grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex would be: `<asp:((?!\brunat\s*=)[^>])*>`. Note that if some attribute value contains "runat=", this won't match.

Comment: Sorry for dummy question, I'm very new to Linux, how call grep with such pattern?

Comment: Unfortunately plain grep does not support lookaheads, but you can do it with Perl using:
`perl -lne "/<asp:((?!\brunat\s*=)[^>])*>/ and print" myfile`

Answer (score 0):

grep -lr "<asp:*" is the command you are looking for I think